# Sum of a column that is a SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that I inherited:

```
SELECT SUM(Credit) AS Total, Account, Date
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        CONVERT(char(10), dbo.vCustomer_Invoice.Accounting_Distribution__Document_Date, 101) AS Date
        , dbo.vCustomer_Invoice.Accounting_Distribution__Amount_Credit AS "Credit"
        , dbo.vCustomer_Invoice.Accounting_Distribution__GL_Account AS "Account" 
    FROM dbo.vCustomer_Invoice 
    WHERE CONVERT(char(10), dbo.vCustomer_Invoice.Accounting_Distribution__Document_Date, 101)  =  '11/03/2020' AND (dbo.vCustomer_Invoice.Accounting_Distribution__GL_Account  LIKE  '4000%' OR dbo.vCustomer_Invoice.Accounting_Distribution__GL_Account  LIKE  '4100-700-%')
)
AS D
Group By Account, Date;
```

This gives me a total by each GL_Account for a date. I'd like to now add a column that Sums by Date. I have in the past used a UNION ALL but I can't get that to work with this query configuration.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SUM()` window function for this new column:

```
SELECT SUM(Credit) AS Total, 
       Account, 
       Date,
       SUM(SUM(Credit)) OVER (PARTITION BY Date) AS Total_By_Date
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT 
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), Accounting_Distribution__Document_Date,101) AS Date,
    Accounting_Distribution__Amount_Credit AS Credit, 
    Accounting_Distribution__GL_Account AS Account 
  FROM dbo.vCustomer_Invoice 
  WHERE CONVERT(CHAR(10), Accounting_Distribution__Document_Date, 101) = '11/03/2020' 
    AND (Accounting_Distribution__GL_Account LIKE '4000%' OR Accounting_Distribution__GL_Account LIKE '4100-700-%')
) AS D
GROUP BY Account, Date;
```

Comment: FORPAS, Thanks. That works great for what I need. I'll have to look into the syntax of the OVER (Partition) line.

Comment: @Belair58 fine if it worked and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.